# pig ToDate(date,'dd/MMM/yyyy') issue

Tags: java, date, datetime, hadoop, apache-pig

I've taken date as chararray stored in `[30/Sep/2015:08:00:36 -0700]` format.

```
test = FOREACH b GENERATE ToDate(SUBSTRING(time,1,12),'dd/MMM/yyyy') AS date;
```

It gives me output like  `2015-10-31T00:00:00.000+05:30`

According to documentation [link](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-date) 2nd argument in ToDate(userstring, format) format is  [Java SimpleDateFormat class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) so it should give output `30/Sep/2015` in datetime format.
I will use that date for sorting purpose.

Comment: Convert using ToDate,sort and format using ToString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Input**

[image: Input]

**Script**

```
A = LOAD 'test12.txt' AS (dt:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToDate(SUBSTRING($0,1,12),'dd/MMM/yyyy');
C = ORDER B BY $0 ASC;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE ToString($0,'dd/MMM/yyyy');
DUMP  D;
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: thank you.
Does it mean 2nd parameter format means in which format you input string ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any ToDate method in the class java.text.SimpleDateFormat (your link).

I've prepared this test to show the consistency of the behaviour

```
@Test
    public void date()
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
        String v="[30/Sep/2015:08:00:36 -0700]";
        try {
            Date d=sdf.parse(v.substring(1,12));
            System.out.println(sdf.format(d));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The output for me is

30/Sep/2015

Hope this can help

Comment: oh sorry forgot to mention link. i am talking about pig's ToDate() function.
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-date